# DELETE Office365 group through unified API return 403

Tags: office365

I am trying to call office365's new unified API to delete groups that the current user owns but it always return 403. the access token I am using is for the user that owns the group.

Request:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/TENANTID/Groups('GROUPID')
```

with Authorization header, Bearer ACCESSTOKEN.

Response:

```
{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."}}}
```

Comment: Does the user have permissions to delete resources? According to [the Azure error codes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/api/graph-api-error-codes-and-error-handling), "a non-administrative principal does not have permission to delete a resource" and would result in a 403.

Answer (score 0):

The permissions scopes are described here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/get-started-with-office-365-unified-api. Unfortunately, for now, you'll need to ask for the *Directory.AccessAsUser.All* permission to be able to delete the group.  We'll be fixing that shortly so that *Group.ReadWrite.All* will permit this.

Hope this helps,